# SSH random crashing

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-12.04

The SSH is getting crashed randomly that i can't login, and sometimes i get kicked out of my session (port closed), i have to restart the SSH service or the Server to make it open again,

```
PORT   STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp closed ssh


ssh: connect to host x.x.x.x port 22: Connection refused
```

No logs shows anything on "auth.log" or "Syslog"

The file system was corrupted before due to creating Superblock in the future, but it was fixed, i am not sure if there is a relation!

Comment: Increase the log verbosity for sshd. My guess is aurora borealis

Comment: If that doesn't work, try stopping the server and starting it manually in debug mode with the -D flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue was due to some tool developer used to change the server time into future times multiple times, that the filesystem got corrupted as while restarting i found the error `"Superblock last write time is in the future` message,

I used live Ubuntu CD, and using the `fsck -yf /dev/sdx`, fixed the all drives, then everything worked fine,